# is it possible to compile program dart to exe on another platform?

Tags: android, linux, dart, exe, cross-compiling

I tried this article https://blog.dantup.com/2019/11/easily-compiling-dart-to-native-executables-for-windows-linux-macos-with-github-actions/, and searched nowhere suitable result,
My problem want to compile a program on the android linux platform into an executable, can it be compiled from the linux pc platform?

Comment: Cross compilation is not supported at this time.  You must be on the target platform.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Not true for all cases. For Android target platform, you can compile on MacOS, Windows, or Linux. For iOS, you can/have to compile on MacOS.

Comment: I interpreted the question about "dart compile exe", which is limited in the way I described.